# How can I get the application name after it has been renamed?

Tags: winapi

After changing the executable name while the application is running, both `GetModuleFileName` and `GetModuleFileNameEx` using PID return the original file name.

How can I get the new file name or even detect the change? Ideally I would prefer not to use `FindFirstChangeNotification`.

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag since this is really a pure Win32 question.

Comment: Perhaps you can open a file handle when the process starts, and use GetFileInformationByHandleEx

Comment: i can only find GetFileInformationByHandle in "windows.pas" but dunno where i can find GetFileInformationByHandleEx

Comment: Define it yourself. A websearch should find a delphi prototype.

Comment: ok it seems like it don't support winxp ,, i'm doing integrity check ,, crc(application.exename); some users using debuggers can pause this code then replace edited exe with the original one to fake the result,, do u have any other idea ?

Comment: Use the file index ....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use QueryFullProcessImageName.

I have met the same problem, and tried GetModuleFileName, GetProcessImageFileName and QueryFullProcessImageName. The last one can work.

This is a simple demo I wrote.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")

void OutputSelfpath()
{
    char szFile[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFile, MAX_PATH);
    printf("GetModuleFileName:\n\r%s\n\n", szFile);

    memset(szFile, 0, MAX_PATH);

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    if (!hProcess)
    {
        printf("OpenProcess failed!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD dwRet = GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, szFile, MAX_PATH);
        if (dwRet)
        {
            printf("GetProcessImageFileName:\n\r%s\n\n", szFile);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("GetProcessImageFileName failed!\n");
        }

        memset(szFile, 0, MAX_PATH);
        DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
        if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, szFile, &dwSize))
        {
            printf("QueryFullProcessImageName:\n\r%s\n\n", szFile);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("QueryFullProcessImageName failed\n", szFile);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* pszFile = "ConsoleTest.exe";
    const char* pszNewFile = "ConsoleTest_bak.exe";
    remove(pszNewFile);

    OutputSelfpath();

    int nRet = rename(pszFile, pszNewFile);

    if (0 != nRet)
    {
        printf("rename file failed!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("################### after rename ###################\n\n");
        OutputSelfpath();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
GetModuleFileName:
E:\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe

GetProcessImageFileName:
\Device\HarddiskVolume3\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe

QueryFullProcessImageName:
E:\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe

################### after rename ###################

GetModuleFileName:
E:\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe

GetProcessImageFileName:
\Device\HarddiskVolume3\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe

QueryFullProcessImageName:
E:\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest_bak.exe
```

I have wrote a blog post about this, see [here](http://www.mazhuang.org/2014/10/09/path-after-rename/).

Comment: You don't need PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS access right here, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION is enough. It is not important for current process, but if you want to get information about other processes - there are some, which can't be opened with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, but can be opened PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION.

Comment: Very useful. I'd just add that `QueryFullProcessImageName` appears to identify filename modification, but not folder name modification. So if your rename action was to `E:\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug_bak\ConsoleTest.exe` instead of `E:\own-sources\ConsoleTest\Debug\ConsoleTest_bak.exe` then `QueryFullProcessImageName` wouldn't spot it.