# Retrieve full path of process in VBScript without WMI

Tags: windows, vbscript, process

I am writing a VBScript that needs to retrieve the full path to the executable corresponding to every running process.

`tasklist` only gives out partial information, and every other solution that I've found involves using WMI, which I cannot assume is available on my target system(s).

Therefore, my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646079/get-a-process-path-with-vbs), except that I need to explicitly support the case where WMI is not available (i.e., disabled).

Is it possible to do this in vanilla VBScript? Or do I need to compile a native executable that can call a Win32 API function, and then invoke that from my VBScript?

Comment: Is it an option to use a separate (compiled) program that isn't installed by default?

Comment: @BrickByBrick you can't get WMI enabled? If you don't have control of the computer what is it you are trying to accomplish? I'm guessing it's disabled for a reason.

Comment: @user692942 that is exactly what I would like to know. Is wmi the only way to get the exe path of a process?
No, wmi cannot be enabled.

Comment: @BrickByBrick I don't have such an external program at hand right now (would need to research it a bit and also test it works without WMI) but what it would need to do (in case you will write it yourself) would be using [the `QueryFullProcessImageName` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew) of the Windows API on the relevant process (after opening it with `OpenProcess`).

Comment: @CherryDT `GetModuleFileNameEx` seems simpler than `QueryFullProcessImageName`. Only possible failure mode I see is if there's a 64-bit/32-bit transition. In that case, `QueryFullProcessImageName` might be preferable.

Comment: @CherryDT In my exploration, I have understood that I could create an exe in C/C++ or VB and then use that in my vbscript program. However, I do not know how, at the moment. Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, and also in case the module file was renamed after it was loaded, [`QueryFullProcessImageName` would return the new name, while `GetModuleFileNameEx` would return the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26271422/1871033). So to avoid possible gotchas, `QueryFullProcessImageName` should be preferred in my opinion.

Comment: @CherryDT Interesting... [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/4b7b3884-d0bb-4812-bc18-2078c61d4b90/queryfullprocessimagename-gives-wrong-path-for-renamed-directory?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) suggests the exact opposite. I have somewhat of a sneaking suspicion that both functions are going to call down to the same native API, but I can't know that for sure without tracing the execution. Never had this issue before. Smacks strongly of an X-Y problem to my ears.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?  You get the idea...

```
Option Explicit
Dim strPSCommand, strDOSCommand, objShell, objExec, strPSResults, strText

strPSCommand = "Get-Process | where { $_.Path -ne $null -and $_.Path -ne '' } | Select Path  -Unique"
strDOSCommand = "powershell -executionpolicy bypass -command " & strPSCommand & ""
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec(strDOSCommand)

Do While Not objExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
    Wscript.Echo strText    
Loop

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objExec = Nothing
```

Comment: Note that this requires PowerShell to be installed. Which may well be fine (it wasn't a limitation called out in the question), but should be noted explicitly, because PowerShell is not *necessarily* going to be present, especially on a machine where WMI has been disabled.